# Upgrade MSVC project from windows phone 8.0 to 8.1

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Microsoft docs state that one should be able to upgrade existing Windows Phone 8.0 project to Windows Phone 8.1:

[image]

However, I cannot see that option in my popup menu:

[image]

I have installed MSVC 2013 Update 2.

Installed components are:

[image]

What have I missed?

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: @ demoncodemonkey Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it might be of help: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42319

Answer (score 0):

You need to be running on Windows 8.1 in order to develop apps for Windows Phone 8.1.

> **Note**  To retarget your project, you must be running Windows 8.1. After you retarget your project, you won't be able to open that project on a computer that runs Windows 8.

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263114.aspx)

and...

> **Important**
>   To create an app, you must use Visual Studio 2013 on a computer running Windows 8.1.
>   You can't create an app by using Windows 7.

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/windows/apps/br211384.aspx)